# npm not installed on for ionic projects

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic3

Good morning Experts, I am stuck for some strange reason on an ionic project I am trying to start up.

`ionic start <name-of-project>`
Works very well,

```
`npm start`
```

Also works very well but I can't install `Android` and `ios` when I run

```
`ionic info`
```

I noticed `npm: not installed`
I have uninstalled and reinstalled node several times and it's still not working please how can I fix this issue. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in your system enviorment variables?
The `PATH` in your machine wide and local setting should have `C:\Program Files\nodejs`
that way it'll find the npm commands.
You'll need to restart your computer after installing npm or after adding something in the system variables.